# Which module for Nginx is the best for HTTP PUSH?

Tags: nginx, server-push

On nginx website they are two module for HTTP PUSH.

Here they are:

http://pushmodule.slact.net/
and
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpPushStreamModule

Wich one is better?

Have you used one of them? Which one do you prefer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I chose HttpPushStreamModule ( https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module ).

It's better. It now supports websockets.

Comment: Are there any specific problems with it? I'm specifically concerned about keeping a messaging queue inside a web server. Not that I'm going to write another Facebook, but the "usual" way was to use Redis/RabbitMQ for message routing. I tested the nginx-push-stream roughly and it looks very, very promising (especially when I considered what I have instead), I'd love to hear more first-hand information about it.

Comment: IGNORE MY LAST COMMENT. I have just found https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module/wiki/Who-is-using%3F and did some reading... looks like Disqus and some other big players are using this module so I guess it will be okay for my 10-user Django site.

Comment: pushmodule.slact.net has since been obsoleted and replaced with https://nchan.slact.net/, which support websockets.

Comment: See also https://github.com/slact/nchan/issues/116

Comment: Just to be clear.... this is not HTTP2 push. Big difference between that and streams. Please correct me if I am wrong.